# sequelize not returning a graphql type

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, sequelize.js, express-graphql

I am following multiple tutorials on the internet and most of them use this implementation where the resolver query method returns a promise where its return type is a graphql typescript generated type. The sequelize returns a different type which is commented in the 2nd snippet.

booking type

```
(alias) type Booking = {
    __typename?: "Booking" | undefined;
    addressId: Scalars['Int'];
    createdAt: Scalars['String'];
    eventId: Scalars['Int'];
    id: Scalars['ID'];
    totalPrice: Scalars['Float'];
    userId: Scalars['Int'];
}
```

```
import Booking

export const BookingsResolvers: IResolvers = {
    Query: {
        async bookings(): Promise<Booking[]> {
            return await BookingModel.findAll(); // the return is not Promise<Booking[]>
        },
    }
};

// when I hover on BookingModel.findAll()
// (method) findAll<Model<BookingAttributes, null>>(this: ModelStatic<Model<BookingAttributes, // null>>, options?: FindOptions<BookingAttributes> | undefined): Promise<...>
```

```
Type 'Model<BookingAttributes, null>[]' is not assignable to type 'Booking[]'.
  Type 'Model<BookingAttributes, null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Booking': addressId, createdAt, eventId, id, and 2 more.
```

when

```
Query: {
        async bookings(): Promise<Model<BookingAttributes, null>[]> {
            return await BookingModel.findAll();
        },
    },
```

error having `null`

```
Type 'null' does not satisfy the constraint '{}'.
```

Booking model definition

```
import { DataTypes, ModelDefined, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

// You can also define modules in a functional way
export interface BookingAttributes {
    id: number;
    totalPrice: number;
    addressId: number;
    userId: number;
    eventId: number;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}

export default (sequelize: any): ModelDefined<BookingAttributes, null> => {
    const Booking: ModelDefined<BookingAttributes, null> = sequelize.define(
        'booking',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            totalPrice: {
                type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
                allowNull: false,
            },
            createdAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE(6),
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: new Date(),
            },
            updatedAt: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE(6),
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: new Date(),
            },
        },
        { tableName: 'bookings', timestamps: true },
    );

    return Booking;
};
```

Comment: Could you show the exact type you get from `BookingModel.findAll()`?

Comment: Could you also add the `BookingModel` definition, including its import to the file